# Git hub switch upload repository

Tags: github, git-push, git-remote

I am developing two apps in Django.

I developed the first (app1) and uploaded it on github (https://github.com/myprofile/app1).
Then, in another separate folder, I developed the second (app2) and uploaded it on another repository on github (https://github.com/myprofile/app2).

Now I modified app1 and I want to upload it on its repository on github.

If I push my files right now, they will fill the app2 repository on github.

How do I tell my prompt to select the repository of app1 as destination of my push?

I think I need something like

```
git remote ??? origin https://github.com/myprofile/app1
```

Comment: Are the 2 apps located in different directories? If so, why don't you just switch to the directory of `app1` and `git push`?

Comment: Anyway, you can change the remote URL with `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myprofile/app1.git`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not exists, since, as one changes the current directory in the command prompt, the url of the repository destination of the files that will be uploaded is already set, because before the repository was associated with the local directory before thanks to the commands

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/myprofile/app1.git
```

Comment: It is not exactly dependent on the "_current directory in the command prompt_". `git init` adds a _.git_ hidden folder in the directory where you ran the command. That folder is the one that stores all the configurations of your repo, including the remote URL where to _push_ your codes. That's what `git` checks. As long as each app is in its own folder with its own _.git_, they will not mix. You can view the current remote URL with `git remote -v` or add or change it to something else.